# Autofixture - how to setup readonly property with some value

Tags: c#, moq, autofixture

I need somehow specify my own value for public read-only property in the tested class

With Moq I can use something like

```
moq.SetupGet(m=>m.SomeReadOnlyProps).Returns(value)
```

then I can use it in the test.

With AutoFixture- I can't do this, since it said that it is read-only:

```
var sut = _fixture.Build<SomeClass>()
     .With(m=>m.SomeReadonlyProperty, value) // here I got exception 
     .Create();
```

Can somebody guide me to use the proper approach for setup read-only property with the usage AutoFixture?

Comment: Yes.. it seems to it is the same. But in general, I in the post marked as an answer - I don't see the clear answer for the proper way... just an explanation of why Build API does not allow setup read-only props.

Comment: I think Fabio's post shows how to define a workaround.